# Jenkins not connecting to windows slave after password update

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, repo

We have a Jenkins, and was working fine without issues. And recently password update was happened, and after that Jenkins build was going through fine for Linux slaves and when trying to checkout repo from Azure Devops it was facing issue as below issue:

```
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https:MyAzureRepo': Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
```

it is unable to checkout the repo and our builds are failing. Can someone provide inputs on the same ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a proxy authentication issue. Since your password was updated, please try restarting your proxy server in case it uses cached credentials.

If that still doesn't work, then please try to reset your proxy for git:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@yourproxy:port
git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@yourproxy:port
```

If certificate is not configured, you may also need to skip the ssl verification:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
git config --global https.sslVerify false
```

Also try to force git to send the credentials and authentication method to the proxy based on your settings (see [http.proxyAuthMethod](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpproxyAuthMethod)):

```
git config --global http.proxyAuthMethod 'basic'
```